# Given a start and end date... find all dates within range in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

Given `DateTime start = startsomething` and `DateTime end = endSomething`

Is there a standard way to return all Dates within start and end such that the return is a list of Dates like ...

```
'1/1/2012 12:00 AM'
'1/2/2012 12:00 AM'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fill a list with all the dates:

```
DateTime begin = //some start date
DateTime end = //some end date
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
for(DateTime date = begin; date <= end; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
    dates.Add(date);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create a method like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> Range(DateTime start, DateTime end) {
  for (var dt = start; dt <= end; dt = dt.AddDays(1)) {
    yield return dt;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you. Had to modify it slightly to return the third day which had an end time of DateTime(2011, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0)  so modified to this ...  for (var dt = start.Date; dt <= end.Date; dt = dt.AddDays(1))

Answer (score 4):

The Linq way:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2012, 6, 1);

var list = Enumerable.Range(0, (end - start).Days + 1).Select(i => start.AddDays(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for generating a date range

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDateRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
  if (endDate < startDate)
    throw new ArgumentException("endDate must be greater than or equal to startDate");

  while (startDate <= endDate)
  {
    yield return startDate;
    startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
  }
}
```

Then

```
GetDateRange(startDate,endDate).Select(d => d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm")).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks everybody. Will test this out and decide on what to use.

Comment: After some testing I decided I liked Jordão response the best. Thanks everyone.